# Generate signed apk android studio, keystore and keytool error

Tags: android, apk, keystore, keytool, generate

When I import eclipse project into android studio then anything is ok, and i'm installing ndk,
but when I want to build my apk, I have this error with keystore :

[image: keystore error]

and when i use keytool i have this error too :

[image: keytool error]

this is my gradle module:

[image: gradle]

i try some solution that i find here, but it's not ok with me
Thanks a lot & best regard :)

Comment: you need to have ndk

Comment: Thanks brother for replay, yes i install ndk from sdk tools, but i don't know where is problem